# Remote connection to VM guest, impossible to see the host?

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, vmware, remote-access

If I accept a remote control session from the guest OS running on a VM, is there any possibility for the user at the other end to see whats going on in the host OS, visually? I guess not, but just wanted to confirm.

Comment: Might depend on what remote control software you are talking about. Can you be more specific?

Comment: Also include which VM host you are using.

Comment: If you look up "virtual machine escape" you find all sorts of exploits that allow an attacker to attack the host from the guest.

Answer (score 0):

An RDP session can only see the windows that it connects to. If that windows is a Virtual Machine, then it can only see and access whatever the Virtual Machine can see.

That means, that if the VM has some form of access to the host, the person using RDP can see that, but nothing more. For example, if you place the VM in the network through a bridged network rather than a NAT network without port forwarding, then one could open up an explorer inside the RDP session and possibly see and use files from the network.

However, in any case, it is not possible for the person connecting to the RDP session to see what image you have on your host's desktop. That is entirely shielded.

But don't forget, if you are still unsure, setup the VM to accept RDP and just RDP in yourself. See what you can see and what you cannot. There is no better way to ensure things are working, and you probably need to test that RDP to the VM is setup correctly anyway.

I exclude a hacker from the above because if a hacker is able to see the host, they no longer use the RDP session that went to the VM, but found a vulnerability to access your host directly.